# Add an outline around the outside of an images texture

Tags: image, textures, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am pretty new to UE4 and was wondering if someone might help me out.

I have a transparent PNG that I'm loading onto an Image node(?) in my widget and was wondering if anyone knew how I would go about drawing an outline around the texture itself, not just the Image node.

Would it just make sense to have two different PNGs? One with the border on it and one without, then when I need it I would just switch what texture is used?

Answer (score 1):

You could create material and try to use sobel filter on alpha channel of your texture.